# How to reboot Windows 7 Home Premium without a mouse?

Tags: windows-7, safe-mode

What are the exact key strokes for rebooting your computer without a monitor while it is in safe mode?

I rebooted my computer in safe mode for some other issues, hence being in safe mode, and it will not load the drivers for the extra monitor.

Answer (score 0):

There are no shortcuts per se, but are a couple of ways you can restart the computer once it's booted up.  You can attempt to open the command line and send the shutdown signal from there, or you can try to use the tab key to get to the shutdown button on the lock screen.  To do the command prompt way:

After you're logged in, hold down the `Windows` key and while you're holding it down, press `R` on your keyboard.
Type in the Letters: `cmd`
Hit the `Enter` key.
Type this in: `shutdown /r /f /t 0`
Hit the `Enter` key.

To restart the system when it's at the login screen, press the `Tab` key three times if you don't have to hold `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Delete` to log in, five times if you do, some systems may take six `Tab`s to get there.
After you've hit the key the required number of times, press the `Space Bar`.
Press `Down` on your keyboard.
Lastly press `Space` again.
If you feel you've made a mistake, then you can hit the `Escape` key to try again if you have to hold `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Delete` to log in.  Alternatively, if you just want to shut the system down altogether, you can press `Tab` 2-4 times and hit `Space` and it should shut the system down.

If everything worked, the system should reboot.

These will all be blind, so good luck.

Comment: Do you start this action as soon as it's turned on or am I required to first enter my password?

Comment: I updated my answer to give more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have an application open, Alt-F4 - R - Enter. If you do have an application open, you can usually hit Alt-F4 - Enter to close it.